# Align icon in Shiny or CSS to the right

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to align an icon to the right of the text in the `tabPanel` object in Shiny. The formatted icon appears by default to the left of labels. How do I move to the right?

The following is the screenshot of my Shiny app.

[image]

Actually, the desired position of the icon (the orange circle) should be like the following.

[image]

I am trying to pass the formatting option `fa-pull-right` as of what I understand from the documentation ([Font Awesome: Bordered + Pulled Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/bordered-pulled-icons)):

```
icon = icon("circle", class = "about-icon", lib = "font-awesome", "fa-pull-right")
```

But this seems to be ignored.
I also try to change the behavior using CSS style in the `tags$style`. There, I change the color, align up, and make it smaller. I am challenged by the pulling to the right.

```
.about-icon   {color:rgb(255, 150, 0); vertical-align: super;
    font-size: xx-small; iconAlign: right}
```

Alternatively, I am not sure how to pass the `fa-pull-right` to the CSS style. For instance, the following also does not work.

```
.about-icon   {color:rgb(255, 150, 0); vertical-align: super;
    font-size: xx-small; fa-pull-right}
```

I attach here the full (simplified) code.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("h2 {font-family: BentonSans Book; font-size:16px}")),

    tags$style(".about-icon   {color:rgb(255, 150, 0); vertical-align: super;
    font-size: xx-small; fa-pull-right ")
  ),
  titlePanel("my App"),
  tabsetPanel(

    tabPanel(
      "Help",
      p("Lorem Ipsum"),
      p("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit")
    ),

    tabPanel(
      "About",
      icon = icon("circle", class = "about-icon", lib = "font-awesome", "fa-pull-right"),
      p("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,"),
      p("sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore"),
      p("et dolore magna aliqua.")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  print("do something")
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a left margin to your icon (and probably a right margin to your title)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fa-pull-right` option is in fact a CSS class. You should put it inside the class parameter of the `icon` function.

```R
icon = icon("circle", class = "about-icon fa-pull-right", lib = "font-awesome")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I hadn't tried this before among the many attempts.